# Swift Type Binding<Set<AnnotationItems.Element.ID>> Meaning

Tags: arrays, swift, generics, mapkit

I know this is kinda a strange question but what type is this `Binding<Set<AnnotationItems.Element.ID>>`?  I really can't conform to this type, a function declared in a package requires this type of variable. I have another variable in the project which is an Array of AnnotationItems. How do I transform that array to this specific type asked?

My array's just a published var in my view model declared like this.
`@Published var locations: [Landmark]`
[Landmark] is seen as AnnotationItems as the attribute before is AnnotationItems and takes [Landmark] without any problem.

This is the signature of the function.
`

```
public init(
        coordinateRegion: Binding<MKCoordinateRegion>,
        type mapType: MKMapType = .standard,
        pointOfInterestFilter: MKPointOfInterestFilter? = nil,
        selectableMapFeatures: MapFeatureOptions = .init(),
        informationVisibility: MapInformationVisibility = .default,
        interactionModes: MapInteractionModes = .all,
        userTrackingMode: Binding<MKUserTrackingMode>? = nil,
        annotationItems: AnnotationItems,
        selectedItems: Binding<Set<AnnotationItems.Element.ID>>,
        @MapAnnotationBuilder annotationContent: @escaping (AnnotationItems.Element) -> MapAnnotation,
        overlays: [MKOverlay] = [],
        @MapOverlayBuilder overlayContent: @escaping (MKOverlay) -> MapOverlay = { overlay in
            assertionFailure("Please provide an `overlayContent` closure for the values in `overlays`.")
            return RendererMapOverlay(overlay: overlay) { _, overlay in
                MKOverlayRenderer(overlay: overlay)
            }
        },
        selectedFeature: Binding<MapFeatureAnnotation?> = .constant(nil)
    )
```

`

I tried different things but of course they didn't work,  like:
`Set(locationManager.locations.map({$0.id}))`
`Set(locationManager.locations.indices)`

Comment: "[Landmark] is seen as AnnotationItems.", what do you mean with this and do you have some more information about the AnnotationItems type?

Comment: I say this because in the same function the attribute before asks me AnnotationItems and I pass [Landmark] without any problems. I give you the signature of the function to better understand what I mean.
` public init(
        userTrackingMode: Binding<MKUserTrackingMode>? = nil,
        annotationItems: AnnotationItems,
        selectedItems: Binding<Set<AnnotationItems.Element.ID>>,
        @MapAnnotationBuilder annotationContent: @escaping (AnnotationItems.Element) -> MapAnnotation`